# jQuery UI draggable-sortable does not work inside an initially inactive tab (jquery ui tabs)

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-tabs, jquery-ui-sortable, jquery-ui-draggable

i'm developing a drag-and-drop interface using **jQuery-UI Draggable** + **jQuery-UI Sortable** inside a **jQuery-UI Tabs**

here's the HTML code:

```
<div id="tabs">
<ul>
    <li><a href="#tabs-1">One</a></li>
    <li><a href="#tabs-2">Two</a></li>
    <li><a href="#tabs-3">Three</a></li>
</ul>
<div id="tabs-1">
    One
</div>
<div id="tabs-2">
    Two
</div>
<div id="tabs-3">
    <!-- BEGIN: DRAG & DROP INTERFACE  -->
    <div class="toolbar">
        <div class="item">
            <div class="in">
                Satu
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="clear"></div>
    </div>

    <div class="sortable">
        <div class="target">
            <div class="clear"></div>
        </div>
    </div>        
    <!-- END: DRAG & DROP INTERFACE  -->
</div>
```

And here's the javascript code:

```
jQuery(function() {    
    jQuery( "#tabs" ).tabs({ selected: 0 });
    jQuery(".sortable .target").sortable({
        opacity: 0.5
    });    
    jQuery(".sortable .item, .toolbar .item").disableSelection();
    jQuery(".toolbar .item").draggable({
        connectToSortable: ".sortable .target",
        helper: "clone",
        revert: "invalid"
    });
});
```

(you can see the whole code here: http://jsfiddle.net/dwiash/CWhFe/)

it works well if the drag-and-drop interface is placed inside a tab that initially shown. But it doesn't work if it placed in an initially inactive/hidden tab. The problem is, the drag-and-drop interface must be placed inside a tab that initially hidden/inactive

Can anyone help me fix this problem?

thx :)

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `tabsshow` event on the tabs to bind the drag'n'drop stuff, http://jsfiddle.net/kMZPR/1/:

```
function initDnD(event, ui) {
    if(ui.index != 2)
        return;
    jQuery(".sortable .target").sortable({ opacity: 0.5 });
    jQuery(".sortable .item, .toolbar .item").disableSelection();
    jQuery(".toolbar .item").draggable({
        connectToSortable: ".sortable .target",
        helper: "clone",
        revert: "invalid"
    });
    jQuery('#tabs').unbind('tabsshow', initDnD);
}

jQuery(function() {
    jQuery("#tabs").tabs({ selected: 0 }).bind('tabsshow', initDnD);
});
```

Note that this unbinds the event as soon as it has done its work, there's no need to keep calling this over and over again; this is also why the `tabsshow` event handler is in a separate named function BTW.

Also, it looks like the jQuery-UI tabs don't call the `tabsshow` event handlers for the initially selected tab. If you want the "Three" tab selected initially then it looks like you're better off doing it by hand rather than through the options:

```
jQuery("#tabs").tabs().bind('tabsshow', initDnD);
jQuery("#tabs").tabs('select', 2);  // Ensure that the event gets triggered
```

You're not doing anything like this in your example, just something that you should be aware off.

This is a fairly common technique when you're dealing with things that need to be fully realized/visible/positioned before they can have extra functionality added.

Answer (score 0):

Wait till the tab is clicked on to activate your draggable/sortable. So, give your `tab-3` link an id:

```
<li><a href="#tabs-3" id="tab3">Three</a></li>
```

And then, change your jQuery to activate your draggable/sortable on click:

```
jQuery(function() {

    jQuery( "#tabs" ).tabs({ selected: 0 });

    $('#tab3').click(function() {
        jQuery(".sortable .target").sortable({
            opacity: 0.5
        });

        jQuery(".sortable .item, .toolbar .item").disableSelection();

        jQuery(".toolbar .item").draggable({
            connectToSortable: ".sortable .target",
            helper: "clone",
            revert: "invalid"
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: Close but not quite there. The above will rewire all the draggable stuff every time tab 3 is clicked rather than just once as is needed. Also, jQuery-UI has custom events for these things and  binding a click handler by hand is sort of going behind its back, using the custom events would be pendantically correct.

Comment: Using `$('#tab3').one('click', ...` instead of `$('#tab3').click(...` would only execute the D'n'D stuff once. The pedants would still be upset but that's what pedants are for.

Answer (score 0):

I know i'm a couple months late, but i just encountered this issue..
Besides this post, I also found this [jqueryui ticket](http://bugs.jqueryui.com/ticket/6261) while searching on the web...

In the ticket a work-around is suggested:

```
$( ".draggable-class-name").draggable({
  connectToSortable: ".sortable-class-name",
  // other options here
  start: function(event, ui) {
      $( ".sortable-class-name" ).sortable("refresh");
  }
});
```

The work-around seems to work ok. This should help a bit, at least until the jqueryui team gets to solving it.

Hope this is useful